# 2 divs in line, right's width = content, left fluids

Tags: html, word-wrap, css

I have 2 horizontal inline-block divs. The parent div fluids 100% width:

- Right div width should be equal to inner element width. So if the inner element is text, the right div's width should be equal to the longest raw in it. As well it would be great if it couldn't exceed for ex. 300px.
- Left div should fluid the rest (remaining) width, no matter what it contains. I have vertical scroll in the left div, so it should stay in the right edge of the left div, and the inner element of right div should start right after it. Is there a way I can archive this only with css? Maybe I should use a table instead of divs?

Check out [**the sketch**](http://jsfiddle.net/2auLxxku/)

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .chat-wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: calc(100% - 25px);
        width: 100%;
    }
    #chatbox {
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        float: left;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="chat-wrapper">
        <div id="chatbox">
            This div should fluid<br> 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>
        </div>
        <div> First row<br> Second row<br>This raw is longest = right div width<br><br> But less than 200px</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: I can't set left div width. Because its equals to calc(100% - right div width). In the sketch the left div width = inner element width, and the right div fluids the remaining space, I want it vice versa

Comment: What about flexboxes? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll want to float the div with the fixed width. In your case, flip the order of the text elements and `float:right` the first text div and set a `max-width` to limit the size. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/punt6nu6/1/).

Comment: Thanks! I just should have flipped the orders of divs to prevent the right div go beneath the left one. I didn't expect that objects order from the right side with float:right.

Answer (score 1):

### only CSS

If you cannot edit HTML, you can achieve it only editing CSS.

Display elements as table and table-cell: http://jsfiddle.net/usgzhv6k/

```
.chat-wrapper {         
    display: table;
}
.chat-wrapper > div:nth-child(2) {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#chatbox {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.create-message-wrapper {
    background-color: cyan;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```